# Magento2 : Custom modules are not installed by Composer

Tags: third-party-module, magento2.2.4

I've installed **Magento 2.2.4** with no sample data from `magento.com/tech-resources/download`.

The problem is that none of about **5 modules** (not installed by composer, just copied into) in `app/code` is workig... They are enabled and I can list them using `module:status`. I've done `setup:di:compile` and cleaned cache.

Does anybody have the similar problem ?

Comment: If you display them in the enabled modules with `module:status` so this means that they are well installed, but did you checked if they are compatible with your current version Magento ?

Comment: Some of them are my own modules and they are quite simple, ex. custom cms_index_index.xml in order to change main page or new route with custom page. They worked fine in Magento 2.2.3

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in configuration opcache in php.ini. Default opcache is disabled and Magento works.